# TypeScript throwing error trying to build massivedecks

Tags: typescript

I am trying to build a personal (i.e. not public facing) [massivedecks](https://github.com/Lattyware/massivedecks/wiki/Deploying) server.  I have installed the latest versions of node.js / npm (12.5.0 and 10.2.5 respectively) as well as the latest version of Typescript (5.3.3).  When I attempt to build the server, i get two errors:

```
**npm run build**

[> @massivedecks/server@2.0.0 build
> npx tsc

src/ts/action/validation.validator.ts:13:24 - error TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof import("/massivedecks/server/node_modules/ajv/dist/ajv")' has no construct signatures.

13 export const ajv = new Ajv({
                          ~~~

src/ts/action/validation.validator.ts:18:1 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("/massivedecks/server/node_modules/ajv-formats/dist/index")' has no call signatures.

18 addFormats(ajv, { mode: "full" });
   ~~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: src/ts/action/validation.validator.ts:13]

(https://stackoverflow.com)

While I have seen suggestions that creating ajv should new new Ajv.default, I don't know if i *should* do that.  I am unable to find any guidance on the addFormats error.

The complete validation.validator.ts can be found here. [[Link](https://github.com/Lattyware/massivedecks/blob/main/server/src/ts/action/validation.validator.ts)]
```

I have installed the latest ajv and ajv-formats (npm i ajv@latest and npm i ajv-formats@latest) with no effect.